# Using Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript to access Google Sites API

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sites

I have a site on google sites which is for members only, and I want to write a mobile app (using PhoneGap) that will provide read-only access to that site.

Is there any way to use [Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/) in order to access [Google Sites API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/) so the mobile app can authenticate itself and query the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start/) to write a script that return the data I need. I authorized the script to access my site (as the script runs as my user), and authorized everyone that has the script URL to execute the script, and then I made my PHoneGap app get the data using the script URL.

Seems like a nice and simple (and free) way to utilize Google cloud services to do what I needed.